# code not executing on catch without Future.delayed

Tags: flutter

when I run the code below, the `print('ERROR')` on `switch` on `builder` of `ValueListenableBuilder` doesn't show up and the `print(value)` on `switch` just show `Status.start`, `Status.loading` and `Status.success`

if I uncomment the `await Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 1));` above of `status.value = Status.success;` on `finally`, the code works normally

why it occurs and how to solve it without `await Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 1));` ?

```dart
// auth_controller.dart
enum Status { start, success, loading, error }

class AuthException implements Exception {
    String title;
    String content;

    AuthException({required this.title, required this.content});
}

class AuthController {
    late final ValueNotifier<bool> state;
    late final ValueNotifier<Status> _status = ValueNotifier<Status>(Status.start);
    late AuthException _error;

    ValueNotifier<Status> get status => _status;
    AuthException get error => _error;

    Future<void> login() async {
        _status.value = Status.loading;

        try {
            UserModel? user =
                await _authenticationRepository.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    emailTextController.text, passwordTextController.text);

            if (user != null) {
                box.write("auth", user);
            }

          _status.value = Status.success;
        }  on AuthException catch (e) {
                _error = e;
                _status.value = Status.error;
        } finally {
            //await Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 1));
            status.value = Status.success;
        }
    }
}
```

```dart
// login_page.dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: _authController.status,
    builder: (_, Status value, __) {
        print(value);
        switch (value) {
            case Status.error:
                print('ERROR');
                //SchedulerBinding
                WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                            content: Text(_authController.error.content)));
                });

                return const Text('Acessar');

            case Status.loading:
                return const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white)
                );

            case Status.start:
            case Status.success:
                return const Text('Acessar', style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.white));
        }
})
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that you don't understand how the notifier works in the thread. When you assign the value, notifyListeners will be called, but this happens synchronously, which means that any other call under the same execution will override the previous one, unless something yields so the UI can update (like the await you have for 1ms). Without it, any previous call will be overridden by the last call. And this happens because regardless of your try/catch, finally will always execute no matter what. Rethink how you're approaching this.